# Docker php:7.4.4-fpm-alpine Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux, fpm

Mysqli functions do not work for me, example:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_init();
?>

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /var/www/html/public_html/test.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/public_html/test.php on line 2
```

Everywhere it is recommended to execute this command inside the container:

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
```

I did it, but it does not help. 
What more can be done?

Comment: More info is needed. Perhaps if you posted a Dockerfile or some kind of docker-compose.yml file then one can see if something is wrong in those areas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490669/docker-fails-to-install-php-mysql-extension/46798563

Answer (score 0):

Running these will solve this issue. (add in `Dockerfile`)

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client --no-install-recommends
    
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```